# How can I return user defined contact groups from the google people API using a curl request?

Tags: php, rest, curl, google-people-api

Using the [Google Developer Api Tool](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list) I have been able to execute a blank query and return a list of contact groups, exactly as expected. When using the same cURL request from my PHP app I don't get anything but some system contact groups (and not all overlap with the tool's response). I can't figure out why this would be the case, am I missing something really obvious?

The Curl Request c&p'd from the google developer tool:

```
    curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

And my php cURL request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$headers = ["Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}", "Accept: application/json"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($result); die();
```

The returned outputs of the requests are in the same format, just the content differs. Does anyone have experience trying to get a list of contact groups/labels from the people api?

Comment: Hi there @David! I strongly advise you to use the [Google API Python client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) to prevent any misconfiguration or faulty tokens. Please test it and write back sharing your findings. Check this [example](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python) if you need help setting it up.

Comment: Please follow my previous comment and check the [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) instead. You may find this [example](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php) useful.

Comment: I’m operating on a hosted server with CPanel and I’m unsure how to actually implement this (I had definitely read it over and over and poked around google but I think it’s beyond what I can implement via my server unless you know something I don’t.  That’s the reason I went with a curl connection instead. It’s just behaving weird.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about where you find difficulties? In the example link you can find a sample script that could work as is just by following the steps. Which step is the problematic one? Please share any error messages too if you get them.